# Why it is good to restore package in dockerfile

Tags: docker

I saw docker file like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["app/WebApplication.csproj", "app/"]
RUN dotnet restore "app/WebApplication.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/app"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
```

I don't understand why we need to do `RUN dotnet restore "app/WebApplication.csproj"` first, isn't `dotnet build` in the last instruction automatically trigger a `dotnet restore` automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a performance thing that makes your builds go faster. Sometimes.

Docker keeps a cache of build layers and checks if you've done what you're doing before. There's a layer for each statement in your Dockerfile.
The Dockerfile you have makes the assumption that you don't change your .csproj file as often as the rest of your code.

Let's say you've done a build and docker has filled its cache. Then you change some code (but not the .csproj file) and build again.
Now Docker can see that up until `COPY . .` everything is the same as last time you built, so it just takes the layers from the cache. So it doesn't actually *do* the `dotnet restore` and that can save a lot of time.

Of course if you change the .csproj file, it has to do the `dotnet restore`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. one more question in regards to cache layer, how does Docker associate cache layers to a particular dockerfiles? Let's say I have this docker file in a folder and this folder has this web application, but I could have another folder also contains the same name of web application (different source code), then how does Docker know which  is the right cache layer to use? or does Docker records the location of Dockerfile? if docker does this, then if I move a folder to another driver, then docker will lose all the cache layers?

Comment: @Hans Kilian, doesn't `dotnet build` also trigger `dotnet restore`?

Comment: Yes, but it also looks to see if the packages are already present. If they are, then it doesn't fetch them again.